# .htaccess redirect all other pages after manual 301's

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla3.2

so we have a whole load of 301 redirect's in out htaccess because we migrated to a new site and a lot of the content is in a different location now. I need to add something to catch the rest of the URL's that aren't manually specified and point them to our homepage.

Comment: Please give examples of the urls that are faulty what youd like to convert them to and so on.

Comment: So atm we have say http://www.webchild.com.au/read/our-blog/introducing-the-august-issue-of-child-mags pointing to http://www.childmags.com.au/2064/6531-introducing-the-august-issue-of-child-mags which was automated, but we don't have http://www.webchild.com.au/read/our-blog/ going anywhere, we want all URL's that aren't currently redirecting to just go to the homepage of the new site. http://www.childmags.com.au

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule **as very last rule (after all of your other rewrite rules)**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=302]
```